# How can I set two Color of background in Card Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm cloning an app called Baedal Minjok.
I need some help...

What I want to make: [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk9a5.png)

but my result : [MyCopy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waiI3.png)

How can I set many backgroundColor in Card Widget? or any Widget has round edge like first picture
It will use many times, so it will be reusable Widget.

Well, this is my first question, so I'm not sure what else need.

I'm so embarrassed, but here's my code

```
class BrandBox extends StatelessWidget {
  String imgLink, name, explain;
  Color boxColor;

  BrandBox(this.imgLink, this.name, this.explain, this.boxColor);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Card(
                color: boxColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                  //side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                //브랜드관과 카드 사이 크기
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: Container(
                  width: 195,
                  //color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                  // BHC, 맵부심.. 등의 글씨들이 있는 박스 전체의 패딩
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        //카드의 시작부터 첫 Text까지의 거리
                        height: 15,
                        color: boxColor,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      Container(height: 3),
                      Text(
                        explain,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
                      ),
                      Container(height: 5),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          FloatingText("쿠폰", imgLink),
                          FloatingText("신메뉴", imgLink),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Text("가을이닭! 매일 2천원 할인"),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: new Image.asset(
                  imgLink,
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Colored card with flutter]

Here is the edited code:

```dart
class BrandBox extends StatelessWidget {
  String imgLink, name, explain;
  Color boxColor;

  BrandBox(this.imgLink, this.name, this.explain, this.boxColor);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 280,
      height: 180,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Card(
            color: boxColor,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 195,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 15,
                          color: boxColor,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                        Container(height: 3),
                        Text(
                          explain,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Chip(
                              label: Text("쿠폰"),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red[200],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 8),
                            Chip(
                              label: Text("신메뉴"),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red[200],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  height: 32,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                          SizedBox(width: 8),
                          Text("가을이닭! 매일 2천원 할인"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Icon(Icons.info, size: 48, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use 'Column' in 'Card':

```
Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(8.0))),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(8.0))),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Using 'Column' will help you to have dynamic height of each section.